# estimate difference of means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

lets say i have 2 random  variables X et Y. I also have N realizations drawns from both X and Y.
For each collection of N samples, i compute the empirical mean of each, lets say x and y.
What are some quantitative properties I can tell about the real mean  of X and Y , from x and y?
I have looked at tests of hypothesis. However it seems to me that the only possible tests will allow me to answer "is the mean of X above the mean of Y" or qualitative properties line this.
Are there statistical tests that allow me to say "the mean of X is x with 99% confidence" or something like this?
thanks!

Comment: it sounds like you want a confidence interval instead of a hypothesis test.